# WeekOfYear -1 SQL HELPP?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, week-number, product-quantity

```
select distinct
pos.DivNo 
,WeekOfYear
,[ProductCode]
,sum(Quantity)[Quantity]
into #sales1
from cbis799p.dbo.pos pos
LEFT JOIN DataWarehouse.dbo.Calendar c on pos.PosDate = c.Datetime
Where pos.DivNo = 772 and ProductCode = '1020'
and WeekOfYear = 1
and YearWeek = 2015
group by pos.DivNo 
,WeekOfYear
,[ProductCode]

select * from #sales1
drop table #sales1


select distinct
pos.DivNo 
,Min(WeekOfYear) WeekOfYear
,[ProductCode]
,SUM(quantity) PreQuantity
into #sales2
from cbis799p.dbo.pos pos
LEFT JOIN DataWarehouse.dbo.Calendar c on pos.PosDate = c.Datetime
where pos.DivNo = 772 and ProductCode = '1020'
and WeekOfYear = 1
and YearWeek = 2015
group by pos.DivNo 
,WeekOfYear
,[ProductCode]

select * from #sales2
drop table #sales2
```

[image]

here is my output 
i need prequantity to come from the week of year - 1 week 
which would make it the 52nd week of 2014

i need this value to come dynamically so that it can be understood by parameters

Comment: @lad2025 thats just going to show me the difference between 2 days

Comment: also the user wants to search on week of year as a parameter

Comment: I don't understand the question.   Is there some reason DATEADD() isn't the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @d Date = '2015-01-01'

    select 
        --Date
        @d
        --WeekYear of Date
        , DatePart(WEEK, @D)
        --Last day of 2014
        , DATEADD(DAY, -1, @D) 
        --Last WeekYear of 2014
        , DatePart(WEEK, DATEADD(DAY, -1, @D))
```

[image]